# What is the difference between "special" and "especial"?

Tags: meaning, differences, adjectives

I can decide accurately which to use in a given context, but I can't make out the actual difference in definition between "special" and "especial". I have searched two authoritative dictionaries to no avail.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In every use, *especial* can be replaced by *special* with no change in meaning. The word *special* does have some meanings *especial* does not have, such as "of or relating to a species" and as a euphemism for handicapped. Also, the phrase *a special* to mean an unusual offer or deal has no corresponding form with *especial*.

Answer (score 10):

I agree with all that David Schwartz wrote in his answer. However, I think someone should tell you that almost nobody uses the word "especial." See this NGram of *special vs. especial*, corpus English, 1800-2008. (The NGram looks similar for both British English and American English.)

I think *especial* sounds affected. Can you give us an example of a sentence in which you think you might use it?

[image]

Comment: Note that the reverse is true for specially vs. especially.

Comment: "I have an especial preference for red cars."

Answer (score 6):

But note that only 'special' can be used as a noun. For example, "Check out the 'specials; on the menu (and not the especials*). Also, in writing, stick to 'especially' rather than 'specially', as the latter is considered informal.

Answer (score 5):

Special conveys a sense of unusual quality.  Especial conveys a sense of more specificity.  Compare:  "This is a special gift for you." with "This gift is especially for you."